# How to escape complicated headlines in org-mode links

Tags: emacs, escaping, org-mode

I have a bunch of journaled pages that look like this:

```
** <2013-12-03 火 20:53> [[http://www.geek.com/science/nasa-funds-fuelless-laser-thruster-could-be-readying-for-test-launch-1573468/][NASA funds fuelless laser thruster, could be readying for test launch | Science! | Geek.com]] :euler:technical:space:


:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       c064d0ae
:END:

The biggest problem for PLT is its limited range...
```

I would like to link to these from other org-mode documents, such as TODO lists. Normally what I do is click on the link, select `Org->Hyperlinks->Store link to here(GLOBAL)`, and then use tab completion with `C-l`.

The resulting link, though, doesn't work and has different formatting:

```
[[file:~/orgs/webjournals.org::*%20%5B%5Bhttp:/www.geek.com/science/nasa-funds-fuelless-laser-thruster-could-be-readying-for-test-launch-1573468/%5D%5BNASA%20funds%20fuelless%20laser%20thruster,%20could%20be%20readying%20for%20test%20launch%20|%20Science!%20|%20Geek.com%5D%5D][<2013-12-03 火 20:53> {{http://www.geek.com/science/nasa-funds-fuelless-laser-thruster-could-be-readying-for-test-launch-1573468/}{NASA funds fuelless laser thruster, could be readying for test launch | Science! | Geek.com}}]]
```

How can I straighten this out? I tried setting simplified text search links like `[[file:~/orgs/webjournals.org::*http:/www.geek.com/]]`, but didn't find any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut the bad string with <kbd>C-w</kbd> and yank it back with
the following command:

```
(defun yank-and-unhex ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (url-unhex-string (current-kill 0))))
```